# Added rows in localDB disappear after closing Visual Studio or cannot be queried?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, localdb

So I have a database filled with values already. It works fine, until I start to query any values I have added into it. It just won't work.

I'm using a project on Visual Studio creating a Web Form, while the database connection, as well as the add, update, and delete methods, are stored in a DLL that I referenced.

The adding works, and so does the updating. I can see it in the database through the server explorer, but I cannot query what I am seeing. I tried querying values I did not add, and it works. When I query the rows I added, it won't work.

Let me know if you need anymore information. I have no idea what's going on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've encountered a similar issue and the catch to it was that it was actually using another database. I'd recommend you check with SQL Server Management Studio and make sure you're using the correct database and also have a look in Webconfig.

Comment: I dropped the database and recreated it. Nothing, yet. What do I need to see in the Webconfig, exactly? By the way, just in case you need to see the Database, you can look at it here. https://db.tt/pZ1Nx4OE

Comment: @yaharga Make sure from within the application that you're querying the correct database. You could look into webconfig too see if you're using the correct one.

Comment: Thank you! I had to drop it twice for it to work. Quite strange. Appreciate sharing your experience!